# Missing node_reference warning

Tags: 7

> User warning: The following module is missing from the file system:
>   node_reference. For information about how
>   to fix this, see [the
>   documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/node/2487215). in trigger_error() (line 1138 of
>   /[localdevetc/drupalrootetc]/docroot/includes/bootstrap.inc). =>

This error usually occurs when module files are removed without a module being disabled and uninstalled first. Typically it's corrected by simply re-downloading the module files and then uninstalling it. The problem is that there doesn't seem to be a module called node_reference for Drupal 7. I tried `drush dl node_reference` and got:

> No release history was found for the requested project
>   (node_reference).
>   Could not download requested project(s).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

node_reference is just a sub-module of the [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) module; that's why you can't download it using Drush. Instead, download the References module.

```
drush dl references
```

Comment: Thanks! I was about to say that I found it in my git history, as a sub-module of references, as you suggested, and was able to checkout an old commit that still contained the sub-module files, copy them to my desktop and then move them into my the latest version. I already had references.